# Swift 3 Mac OSX - can't cast SecCertificate object in my Keychain to SecKeychainItem?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, security, keychain

I am trying to delete an identity from my Keychain in Swift 3.0. My code is currently:

```
var idCert: SecCertificate? = nil
var idKey: SecKey? = nil
SecIdentityCopyCertificate(id, &idCert)
SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(id, &idKey)
SecKeychainItemDelete(idCert as! SecKeychainItem)
SecKeychainItemDelete(idKey as! SecKeychainItem)
```

"id" is a SecIdentity object that I got by using SecItemCopyMatching to get all of my identities, and then used that list to find the identity associated with a specific email address.
My code fails when I try to cast idCert to SecKeychainItem. [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seccertificate) says:

> A SecCertificate object for a certificate that is stored in a keychain
>   can be safely cast to a SecKeychainItem for manipulation as a keychain
>   item. On the other hand, if the SecCertificate is not stored in a
>   keychain, casting the object to a SecKeychainItem and passing it to
>   Keychain Services functions returns errors.

but upon checking Keychain Access I can plainly see that the certificate is in the Keychain. What is going on? Is it possible for a certificate to appear to be in my Keychain but actually isn't or can't be found for some reason? Is there a way for me to programmatically check if the SecCertificate object is in my Keychain?

Comment: I figured out a solution to my problem-- just use SecItemDelete and define my query with kSecClass, kSecMatchEmailAddressIfPresent, and kSecMatchIssuers. However, I'm still not sure why my certificate object would not cast to SecKeychainItem.